# I am getting the following error

Tags: support, answers, new-users

I am getting the following page whenever I try to submit an answer for the questions.

[image]

Comment: If you read through the page, as suggested, you'd have found your solution at the bottom.

Comment: What makes you think the page is an error? Did you read it?

Comment: Guys, what if it's a language barrier?

Comment: The screenshot looks like a variant of http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and the URL in the screenshot agrees (visiting it with `/questions/` instead of `/help/` just redirects to `/help/`), but the parameter seems to bring up a slightly modified version.  What's the mechanism here?  Is it documented?

Comment: @tripleee I'm not sure if it's documented, but it's something new users get when their answer is determined to be potentially "bad" by the automated quality heuristics (I believe) - e.g. the answer contains text like "I have the same problem", or consists only of a link.

Answer (score 23):

Read the page you are screenshotting, carefully.